# How to transfer an object with delegation pattern to another VC?

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates

i have an app which contains information about bars.
a listViewController holds each Bar object in a cell (name, address, phone etc).

when i press the cell i move to the infoViewController which display the data, but for some reason it dosn't work

this is the code in the TableView -

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
    indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let barSelected = bars[indexPath.row]

      let infoVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "infoViewController") as! InfoViewController

    chooseBarDelegate?.chooseBar(barChosen: barSelected)
    present(infoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the class is conforming to the protocol i created -

import Foundation

```
   protocol barInfoDelegate {
   func chooseBar(barChosen:Bar)
    }
```

and i also created an instance of the delegate -

```
var chooseBarDelegate:barInfoDelegate?
```

in the detailViewController i created a var with optional object -

```
var infoBar:Bar?
```

and added an extension -

```
extension InfoViewController: barInfoDelegate {
    func chooseBar(barChosen: Bar) {
        infoBar = barChosen
    }   
}
```

i've also set the the delegate to self in infoViewController

```
    listViewController.chooseBarDelegate? = self
```

The app doesn't crash but the information dont pass.
When i;m checking in the debugger using print object i can see that "barSelected" does contain an object, but infoBar is nil.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for the delegate at all. Get rid of the protocol, the `chooseBarDelegate` property, and the `barInfoDelegate` extension on `InfoViewController`. The only thing you need to keep is the `var infoBar:Bar?` property of `InfoViewController`.

Then replace this line:

```
chooseBarDelegate?.chooseBar(barChosen: barSelected)
```

with:

```
infoVC.infoBar = barSelected
```

Comment: First of all - thank you very much for your answer! it works of course. 
I thought to do it with delegate because i need to pass data also from another vc (mapVC) to the same infoVC, so i thought delegate pattern will be better, cause i will just need to conform to the protocol.
Guess i was wrong?...

Comment: The infoVC would want to use a delegate when the infoVC has a need to ask (or tell) another view controller for something and you don't want to hardcode who that other view controller will be. But it sounds like you have two cases where a view controller creates an infoVC and the original view controller needs to give data to the infoVC. That's the opposite of when you would use a delegate.